# How to make UITabBarController load view controllers lazily?

Tags: iphone

I have a UITabBarController created programaticaly that manages 4 subclasses of UIViewController. Something like:

```
//Create Controller 1
    self.terminal = [[[TerminalController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TerminalView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController* navTerminal = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:terminal] autorelease];
    navTerminal.title = __(@"Terminal");
    navTerminal.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    navTerminal.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_terminal.png"];        

    //Create Controller 2
    self.history = [[[HistoryController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HistoryView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController* navHistory =  [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:history] autorelease];
    navHistory.title = __(@"History");
    navHistory.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    navHistory.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_history.png"];

    //Create Controller 3
    self.settings = [[[SettingsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController* navSettings =  [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings] autorelease];
    navSettings.title = __(@"Settings");
    navSettings.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    navSettings.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_settings.png"];

    //Create Controller 4
    HelpController* help = [[[HelpController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController* navHelp =  [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:help] autorelease];
    navHelp.title = __(@"Help");
    navHelp.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    navHelp.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_help.png"];

    //Create Tab Bar an add it's view to window.
    self.tabBar = [[[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    tabBar.viewControllers = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:navTerminal, navHistory, navSettings, navHelp, nil] autorelease];
    tabBar.delegate = self;     

    [window addSubview:tabBar.view];
```

Is there a way to tell the UITabBarController to load the view controllers lazily? ej, when the user clicks one of the tab bar items or when tabBarController setSelectedIndex is called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm doing this very thing in one of my apps.  The trick is to make your view controller NOT be a subclass of UITabBarController, but rather UIViewController, and implement UITabBarDelegate.  I created the view for this in IB, laying out the tab bar (with the proper # of buttons, images, tags, etc.) and a placeholder UIView which is used to properly place the subviews that are swapped in and out.  View switching happens on tabBar:didSelectItem:  It looks something like this:

```
// MyTabBarController.h
@class MyFirstViewController;
@class MySecondViewController;
@class MyThirdViewController;

@interface MyTabBarController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIView *placeholderView;
    IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
    MyFirstViewController *firstViewController;
    MySecondViewController *secondViewController;
    MyThirdViewController *thirdViewController;
    UIViewController *currentViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyFirstViewController *firstViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MySecondViewController *secondViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyThirdViewController *thirdViewController;

- (void) switchToView:(UIViewController*)aViewController;
@end


//  MyTabBarController.m
#import "MyTabBarController.h"
#import "MyFirstViewController.h"
#import "MySecondViewController.h"
#import "MyThirdViewController.h"

enum {
    kView_First = 1,
    kView_Second,
    kView_Third
};

@implementation MyTabBarController

@synthesize firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    // Default to first view.
    tabBar.selectedItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    MyFirstViewController *viewController = [[MyFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
    self.firstViewController = viewController;
    [viewController release];
    [self switchToView:firstViewController];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Tell our subview.
    if( currentViewController != nil ) {
        [currentViewController viewWillAppear:animated];
    }
}

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    switch (item.tag) {
        case kView_First: {
            if (firstViewController == nil) {
                MyFirstViewController *viewController = [[MyFirstViewController alloc]
                    initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
                self.firstViewController = viewController;
                [viewController release];
            }

            [self switchToView:firstViewController];
        }
        break;

        case kView_Second:
            if (secondViewController == nil) {
                MySecondViewController *viewController = [[MySecondViewController alloc]
                initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
                self.secondViewController = viewController;
                [viewController release];
            }

            [self switchToView:secondViewController];
            break;

        case kView_Third: {
            if (timesViewController == nil) {
                MyThirdViewController *viewController = [[MyThirdViewController alloc]
                initWithNibName:@"ThirdView" bundle:nil];
                self.thirdViewController = viewController;
                [viewController release];
            }

            [self switchToView:thirdViewController];
        }
        break;              
    }
}

- (void) switchToView:(UIViewController*)aViewController {
    if( aViewController == currentViewController ) return;

    UIView *aView= aViewController.view;                
    [aViewController viewWillAppear:NO];
    if( currentViewController != nil ) {
        [currentViewController viewWillDisappear:NO];
        [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];       
    }
    aView.frame = placeholderView.frame;
    [self.view insertSubview:aView aboveSubview:placeholderView];
    if( currentViewController != nil ) {
        [currentViewController viewDidDisappear:NO];
    }
    [aViewController viewDidAppear:NO];
    currentViewController = aViewController;
}
@end
```

The code could surely be made more DRY, but you get the idea.

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP and this code worked perfectly for me. Thanks!! I was able to bring my app startup time down by 2 full seconds.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing some more work and testing with this and ran into a problem. If I present a Modal View Controller and then dismiss that modal, when I get back to the Tab Controller its interface is all screwed up. My UITabBar has moved, the UIView that is the subview of the custom tab bar controller has stretched to fill more of the screen. Have you run into problems like this and if so, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Kenny Wyland, I have not had any troubles like this, but I don't think I've ever tried to display a modal view over it.  I can't think of any reason off the top of my head that it would misbehave like that, however.

Comment: +1  I need to roll my own UITabbarController-like root controller for a project and I wasn't sure about how to manage the sub-viewcontrollers, this gives me enough to get going, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

What are you trying to load lazily?

This is a pretty standard UITabBarController implementation.  I have one very similar to it in an application I am writing.  In my code the viewDidLoad (the method called after a controller has loaded its associated views into memory) is not called until the tab is touched.

I do believe the way you have coded (aside from all of the autoreleased objects) is the preferred method of creating this kind of UI.

Comment: Is releasing preferred to autoreleasing? why is that?

Comment: Releasing an object frees the memory immediately, whereas an autoreleased object has to wait for the pool to drain.  On a desktop computer this might not be an issue, but in the world of the iPhone memory is a limited commodity.

One of the WWDC '09 video's on memory managment specifically recommends against using autorelease in situations like this where there is no reason other than code shorthand.

Comment: @Lounges i am new to iOS development...can you please explain me how this tab controller actually works? how and when it load its views to memory and how long it remains in memory

Answer (score 3):

A UITabBarController requires that actual view controllers be set for its `viewControllers` property - there's no lazy loading available from Apple's frameworks. The tab bar controller relies on certain aspects of the controllers it loads for its properties. However, it doesn't call `viewDidLoad` until the tab is pressed for the first time.

What you can do instead is create your own "placeholder" view controller that, in its `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` methods, replaces itself in the tab bar controller with its actual view controller. That way, you can minimize the memory used by the view controllers held by the tab bar controller until you load a certain tab's view controller and replace it with your more memory- and processor-intensive controller.

Side note: You'll want to change the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` property directly, rather than use the `setViewControllers:animated:` method, so that your users don't see an animation every time you load a new controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can always not use a UITabBarController and manage the tabbar urself, when someone selects a tab u push the viewcontrollers view in in the didSelectIndex method

Answer (score 0):

Within the custom UITabBarController's didSelectItem method, you should simply just make this call:

```
[self setSelectedViewController :[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]];
```