# Lazy loading of UIViewController in an iOS 5 containment view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, lazy-loading

I want to write my own `UITabbarController` replacement in an iOS5-only iPad app. Much like the one I found on GitHub [MHTabBarController](https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController). I read the code and found that he allocates all his viewControllers upfront:

```
ListViewController *listViewController1 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
ListViewController *listViewController2 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
ListViewController *listViewController3 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:listViewController1, listViewController2, listViewController3, nil];
MHTabBarController *tabBarController = [[MHTabBarController alloc] init];

tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

the implementation of the setter looks like this:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)newViewControllers
{
    _viewControllers = [newViewControllers copy];
    for (UIViewController *viewController in _viewControllers)
    {
            [self addChildViewController:viewController];
            [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

the setter for `setSelectIndex:` then gets the right UIViewController and calls `addSubview` on self with the UIViewControllers view.

It bugs me that he implements it with the three `ListviewController` fully initiated. I found myself remembering articles about implementing large scrollViews with lazy loading, but I can't find anything on google, nor do I remember the implementation details.

So the question is, who do I implement lazy loading, so that the UIViewController will load just as the user tabs on the tabbar with the associated UIViewController.

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question, if you still need it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197838

Answer (score 0):

You should implement lazy loading. You never know how heavy a `UIViewController` can be. Well it depends of how far have you implemented. Do you already have the buttons to switch tabs? If so, on click, just add the corresponding `UIViewController` to the `UIView`. When you click another, you can hide it and add another `UIViewController`.

Comment: I'll have buttons to switch the tabs. I had in mind that after tapping a button, the button calls a method with an index to switch the content of the view controllers. With the index it will lookup the matching VC in an array full of VCs (the array is already there because of the iOS 5 containments). From there on I don't know how to  do it — did you mean NSClassFromString()?

Comment: I did a custom UITabBarController myself a few months ago, what I did, was to keep a reference to all the UIViewControllers and when I needed to switch, I would remove the one that I was showing from the UIView and add the new one.

Comment: Okay, you will not load the view, but you have to have allocate space and initialize the VCs, right?

Comment: Only when you need them. At the end, you will have all the 3 UIViewControllers (if the user goes to all the 3 tabs). If the user just went to one, only 1 UIViewController would be used. :)